# Why there is not centralized authorization solution/product?

Tags: authentication, authorization, single-sign-on

Correct me if I am wrong , I done bit of search on both centralize authentication and authorization , it is easy to find quite a few centralize authentication solution (SSO?) ,but as for authorization seems not much .

Is that means  authorization is easy to implemented as extend/plugin of central authenticate or it is not a good idea to be centralize ? like oAuth is decentralized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They exist. You want to look at *externalized authorization management*. The standard behind is XACML, the eXtensible Access Control Markup Language.

The solutions in this space are:

- Open-source

  - JBoss PicketBox
  - SunXACML
  - WSO2
  - HerasAF
- Vendor

  - Axiomatics
  - IBM Tivoli
  - Oracle

In addition you may want to consider frameworks e.g. Spring Security, Ruby's CanCan, PHP's Yii...